# IntelliJ IDEA: List of defined git tags

Tags: git, intellij-idea

Where can I find a list of defined git tags in IntelliJ IDEA (without using command line interface)?

Comment: I can't see a way to do it. I always just use `git tag`.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

As @alex mentions, it is currently not possible to view tags (you can only view branches). You may want to watch and/or vote for:

- [IDEA-74492 Git: Checkout tag or revision: provide a list of available tags in combobox](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-74492)
- [IDEA-102284 Tags in Git Branches popup](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-102284)

Comment: Thanks, upvoted the requests :-) really like to see this feature being added!

Comment: This is downright unacceptable for a platform of the size and popularity of IntelliJ....

Answer (score 6):

There are a couple of ways to do it, neither very obvious or user friendly.

### Option 1

Click on the magnifying glass icon in the top right of the VCS log panel (not the top left!). This brings up a weird little window in which you can search for tags, or hit `Ctrl-Space` to show a list of all branches and tags.

[image: Screenshot of the git log panel in IntelliJ]

### Option 2

Use the `Checkout Tag or Revision...` command. I don't think there's a button for this but you can find it in the global search. Then hit `Ctrl+Space` to bring up the same list of tags and branches as in option 1.

[image: Screenshot of the checkout dialog]