# How to push Git TAGs from IntelliJ without using the console?

Tags: git, intellij-idea

Is there a way to push git tags from IntelliJ without bringing up the console and typing `git push origin master --tags`?

Answer (score 92, accepted):

You can create a tag in VCS -> Git -> Tag... menu.

Then open the push dialog with VCS -> Git -> Push and activate the checkbox "Push Tags".

Comment: Right under my nose! Thanks. By chance, would you know how to list the tags without `git tag` on terminal?

Comment: @MateusViccari there is currently no way to list the tags except through terminal. There is a topic on this [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27817458/intellij-idea-list-of-defined-git-tags)

Answer (score 8):

In IntelliJ

You can go to

1. logs
2. select commit line you want to tag
3. right-click on it and select 'new tag'
4. give a tag name and press 'ok'
5. push

Make sure you check the push tags checkbox

[image]